# How to cross reference user input and return only exact matches

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

My program cross-references a user's inputted list of ingredients with names in my database and returns exact matches of items in the list (not the list itself) to names in the database.

Ingredients in the database have names up to 4 words long, also including spaces numbers, dashes and bracketed words. The user inputs a single item, or list of items and only the matches from the database are outputted on the results page. The users search can return only exact matches, as anything else would skew the results.

An example inputted list would look like this:
Avene Thermal Spring Water (Avene Aqua), Bis-Ethylexyloxyphenol Methoxyphenyl Triazine, Diethylhexyl Butamido Triazone, Butyl Methxydibenzoylmethane, Benzoic Acid, Caprylyl Glycol, Tocopheryl Glucoside, Polysorbate 20, Excipients, Methylene Bis-Benzotriazolyl Tetramethylbutylphenol [Nano]

And example matches would return as:
Methylene Bis-Benzotriazolyl Tetramethylbutylphenol [Nano],
Polysorbate 20,
Excipients

The inputted list is split into an array, then intersected with the array of ingredient names. If there are any matches, they are printed out in my view. The method is below.

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController

  def search  
      @parameters = params[:search].downcase.split(/, /)  
      @results = @parameters & ingredient_names
  end

private

  def ingredient_names 
  @ingredient_names = Ingredient.pluck :name
  end
end
```

This code functions correctly, but it's not very user friendly as it requires the user to input a list with each item separated by a comma and a space. If there are any mistakes in the input (eg. no space between comma and next word) no matches will be returned. I want to know if there is another way to implement this that is more user friendly, while still maintaining the exact matches.

Comment: you can do `@parameters = params[:search].downcase.split(',').strip` and this will at least take care of any leading or trailing whitespace between the items in the list.

Comment: So when you say exact matches, you mean certain non-exact matches involving exact matches of certain parts. So "exact match" is misleading.

Comment: The strip method doesn't work on arrays, but I can call it on the string before it is split. I would also need to strip the spaces from the names in the database before they get matched, but it does deal with the space problem in the user input.

Comment: Not an exact match to the list, but exact matches to items in the list. It can't return partial matches of items or names in the database. I will clarify that.

Comment: You say "it's not user friendly". What does this exactly mean in the context of a controller? It's the front end's duty to make a user friendly form that sends the request with the correct params.